# Troubleshooting Wireless Router: Is it bad or is it being impacted by traffic or a device

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a TP-LINK wireless router. It has worked perfectly for months. Now it needs multiple resets per day. How can I troubleshoot it to see if it is flat out gone bad, or if somehow a single device or type of traffic is causing the issue?

Devices cannot connect wirelessly. They can see the SID, but the router rejects the password. When I reboot the router, everything reconnects fine. There are 6 wireless devices continuously connected. Another 5 occasionally.

Are there common troubleshooting steps for this?

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing prior to performing a reset?

Comment: Devices cannot connect wirelessly. They can see the SID, but the router rejects the password. When I reboot the router, everything reconnects fine.

Comment: Can you edit the question with that information? How many devices are connecting? Can you also provide the exact model number?

Comment: Model WR841N v9 00000000
I just updated firmware to 3.16.9 Build 150401 Rel.58806n and set myself a reminder to circle back here if the issue goes away.

Answer (score 1):

There is no excuse for a router to need to be reset regularly.

Regardless of what the trigger happens to be, the real problem is either buggy firmware or buggy or failing hardware. Update your firmware to the latest from the manufacturer, and see if that solves the problem. If not, you could try an aftermarket firmware distro such as OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Tomato, etc.

If you can't find firmware that doesn't crash, you probably have a hardware problem.

Comment: I will try the firmware update and report back. Thanks.

Comment: No luck. Wireless is dropping out for all devices. Yesterday it happened 4 times and only one of them 'fixed' itself after an hour. I have to power cycle the router. I have ordered a replacement. It does not seem logical that hardware would partially fail like this. It seems more likely that one of the wireless clients is doing something new/odd that is causing it.